# How to equals Kotlin & Java BasicTypes

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to `getTypeByClass()` in my Android Application. This function is exchange the class to string.

```
    public fun getTypeByClass(type: Class<*>): String {
        return if (type == String::class.java) {
            "TEXT"
        } else if (type == Long::class.java) {
            "INTEGER"
        } else {
            "NULL"
        }
    }
```

```java
   System.err.println(getTypeByClass(Long.class));
```

The output is NULL，but i need INTEGER.

And i decompile the class

```java
return Intrinsics.areEqual(type, String.class) ? "TEXT" : (Intrinsics.areEqual(type, Long.TYPE) ? "INTEGER" : "NULL");
```

`Long::class.java` is corresponding `Long.TYPE`

Comment: It's work. I test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`KOTLIN`**

[Kotlin Playground: Edit, Run, Share Kotlin Code Online](https://pl.kotl.in/yObKlEDz3)

```
 /**
 * You can edit, run, and share this code. 
 * play.kotlinlang.org 
 */

fun main() {
    println("Hello, world!!!")
    var var1 = 10L as Long 
    println(getTypeByClass(var1::class.java))
}
fun getTypeByClass(type: Class<*>): String 
{
        return if (type == String::class.java) {
            "TEXT"
        } else if (type == Long::class.java) {
            "INTEGER"
        } else {
            "NULL"
        }
 }
```

**`JAVA`**

```
    /******************************************************************************

                            Online Java Compiler.
                Code, Compile, Run and Debug java program online.
Write your code in this editor and press "Run" button to execute it.

*******************************************************************************/

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long x = 10L;
        String s = "";
        System.out.println(getType(s));
    }
    public static String getType(Object object)
    {
        if(object.getClass().equals(Long.class) || object.getClass().equals(Double.class) || object.getClass().equals(Integer.class) || object.getClass().equals(Float.class))
        {
            return "INTEGER";
        }
        else if(object.getClass().equals(String.class))
        {
            return "STRING";
        }
        return "UNKNOWN";
    }
}
```

Comment: I used this function in `Java`

Comment: Didn't have other solution?

Comment: @xixihaha check

Comment: @xixihaha glad to help you sir

Answer (score 0):

You can use **is** operator. Refer this for type checks and cast in kotlin
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html

Comment: `is` is used for object，but my input is `class`